# Nested Set Filtering

Tags: mysql, nested, set

I'm using nested set model for my menu tree, and I'm trying to get nodes with some filtering. I have several root nodes.
Example:

```
Menu1(on)
 \-Submenu1(on)
 \-Submenu2(on)
Menu2(off)
 \-Submenu3(on)
 \-Submenu4(on)
    \-Submenu5(on)
Menu3(on)
```

I want to return all nodes "on" but not the ones that have parents "off". 
The query, for the example above, should return only Menu1 (and children) and Menu3.

```
Menu1(on)
 \-Submenu1(on)
 \-Submenu2(on)
Menu2(on)
 \-Submenu3(on)
 \-Submenu4(off)
    \-Submenu5(on)
Menu3(on)
```

For this example, the query should return all except Submenu4 and it's children.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642447/counting-records-belonging-to-a-category-in-mysql/3642539#3642539

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM sometable AS t0
LEFT JOIN sometable AS t1 ON t0.lft BETWEEN t1.lft AND t1.rgt AND t1.active='off'
WHERE t1.lft IS NULL
ORDER BY t0.lft
```

That is, select each row where there is no row with `off` that contains (or is the same row as) the target row.